# Csrf verification failed in Django with gunicorn and gninx

Tags: django, forms, security, file-transfer

I'm currently trying to adjust my django server with gunicorn and gninx.

I met several issues when I tried to upload files :

- with time-out which I solved by adjusting gninx and gunicorn parameters. SOLVED
- with file's max_size which I solved by adjusting gninx parameters. SOLVED
- with "csrf verification failed" :

  - I added the following settings 
    : 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
  - I added the crsf_token in each of my forms
  - Upload works for little files but I would like to upload file with a max_size of 70Go. I tried to upload 10Go files, it works. I tried to upload 20Go files, and "scrf verification failed" happened.

So I have several questions :

- Where does this issue could come from?
- Given that it takes a lot of time to transfer files, could the csrf_token be "outdated"?
- Do you have some ideas/pointers in order to solve this issue?

EDIT : i found some people who speak about :

- cookies issues which can be corrected in settings

EDIT2 : If it can be useful:

- on google chrome > develloper > application > cookie > http column, csrf is not checked